# Find a Basis from a linear span with trigonometric functions

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, span

So I'm having doubts about this problem.

> Let
>   $$
> V=\operatorname{span}\{2, 3\sin(x)\cos(x), \cos(2x)-1,\sin(2x)+1,\cos^2(x),\sin^2(x)\}
> $$
>   Find a basis for $V$.

I reduced it to $$V=\operatorname{span}\{3\sin(x)\cos(x),\cos^2(x),\sin^2(x)\}$$
using trigonometric identities and I don't think I can reduce it anymore, but I am not quite sure, would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try evaluating each function at a few points like $x=0,\pi/6,\pi/2$.  Then we can write the matrix $\pmatrix{3\sin(0)\cos(0) & \cos^2(0) & \sin^2(0) \\ 3\sin(\pi/6)\cos(\pi/6) & \cos^2(\pi/6) & \sin^2(\pi/6) \\ 3\sin(\pi/2)\cos(\pi/2) & \cos^2(\pi/2) & \sin^2(\pi/2)} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \\ 3\sqrt{3}/4 & 3/4 & 1/4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$.  This is clearly a full rank matrix so those three functions are linearly independent.

Comment: @Bye_World: Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't feel like explaining any more than I did.  If someone else wants to write it out as an answer in more detail they can go for it.

Comment: @Bye_World Oh, that definitely makes sense, I really hadn't thought about that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You wish to show the functions $f(x)=3\sin x\cos x$, $g(x)=\sin^2 x$, and $h(x)=\cos^2 x$ are linearly independent.  So suppose we have a linear relation $$af(x)+bg(x)+ch(x)=0$$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$; we wish to show that $a=b=c=0$.  To show this, we can try plugging in some values for $x$.  For instance, setting $x=0$, we have $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $h(0)=1$, so we get $$0=af(0)+bg(0)+ch(0)=c,$$ so $c=0$.  Setting $x=\pi/2$, we have $f(\pi/2)=0$ and $g(\pi/2)=1$, so we have $$0=af(\pi/2)+bg(\pi/2)=b.$$  So our relation is actually just of the form $af(x)=0$.  Now just plug in any value of $x$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$ to conclude that $a=0$.